# Probability Distribution over a coomon finite alphabet

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

Can anyone please give a hint about how to solve this problem? I donot how to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just let the alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ to be, without loss of generality, $\{1,2,\dots,N\}$. With this,  you have,
$$
\|p_k-p\|_{TV}\to 0 \iff \lim_{k\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^N |p_k(j)-p(j)| =0.
$$
That is, for every $j\in[N]$, $|p_k(j)-p(j)|\to 0$, as $k\to \infty$, thus, $|p_k(j)-p(j)|^2 \to 0$, and thus, $\sum_{j=1}^N |p_k(j)-p(j)|^2 \to 0$, which says nothing but $p_k\to p$ in $L^2$ sense.